# Container app unable to connect from web browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-lightsail

I wrote a container web app and built it with docker, after it appears to be running, the app is not accessible through typing the link in the browser, but only available through local access link. The same container app always shows 404 No Such Service when pushed to AWS

here is the dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

EXPOSE 2328

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY main.py /app
COPY Templates /app/templates
COPY blockSchedule.txt /app
COPY blockSchedule.txt /app

CMD [ "python", "./main.py", "production" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you included the commands that you ran and the output that you observed.

I suspect that you're not publishing the container's port (possibly 2328) on the host.

If there is a Python server and it's running on 2328 in the container, you can use the following command to publish (forward) the port to the host:

```sh
docker run \
--interactive --tty --rm \
--publish=2328:2328 \
your-container-image:tag
```

> **NOTE** replace `your-container: tag` with your container's image name and tag.

> **NOTE** The `--publish` flag has the following syntax `[HOST-PORT]:[CONTAINER-PORT]`. The container port is generally fixed by the port used by the container but you can use whichever host port is available.

Using the command above, you should be able to e.g
browse the container from the host using e.g. `localhost: 2328`